# app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: android, gradle

### Command

gradle clean build --info

### Error info

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.   
> java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 23
  Exception Details:
    Location:
      com/example/Eventbus/annotation/ThreadMode.(Ljava/lang/String;I)V @12: ifeq
    Reason:
      Expected stackmap frame at this location.
    Bytecode:
      0x0000000: 2a2b 1cb7 0006 b200 3db6 0041 9900 0bb2
      0x0000010: 0047 1249 b600 4fb1
```

### IDE info

1. Mac OX 10.10.5
2. Android Studio 2.0
3. Android SDK 23.0.2
4. Gradle 2.10
5. JDK 1.8_77
6. Maven 3.2.3

Comment: What exactly is your problem here?

Comment: I can't fix this app build error.

Comment: @JinmiaoOuyang see my answer bellow...let me know if it doesnt worked..

Answer (score 0):

Recompile all sources with JDK 1.7.
If you are using java 1.8, remove XX:-UseSplitVerifier and use -noverify in your JVM properties.I ran into this problem and try using the flag -noverify which really works. It is because of the new bytecode verifier. So the flag should really work.
I am using JDK 1.7.

Comment: @JinmiaoOuyang try restart and clean and then run

Comment: then change your build tool version